# Reschedule a Oracle Job

Tags: oracle, scheduler

The  Oracle job running two times  a day with following time interval

```
FREQ = DAILY; BYHOUR = 6,12; BYMINUTE = 30
```

Now  I need to  Reschedule  the jobs to run at 8 AM and 12:30 PM. I cannot do it without disturbing already running 12:30 schedule.

Answer (score 2):

Query if the job is running using:

```
select owner , job_name , running_instance, session_id from all_scheduler_running_jobs
order by owner , job_name
```

And change your interval to:

```
FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=8,12;BYMINUTE=0,30;BYSETPOS=1,4
```

The `SETPOS` works in below way:

```
╔═══╦══════╦════════╗
║ P ║ Hour ║ Minute ║
╠═══╬══════╬════════╣
║ 1 ║    8 ║     00 ║
║ 2 ║    8 ║     30 ║
║ 3 ║   12 ║     00 ║
║ 4 ║   12 ║     30 ║
╚═══╩══════╩════════╝
```

Comment: This will cause the job to run daily, 4 times per day: 8AM, 8:30AM, 12PM, and 12:30PM, which doesn't sound like that is what the OP wants.

Comment: @KrisJohnston Thanks for comment! You are right. I forget to include `BYSETPOS=1,4`

Comment: Interesting... I didn't realize you could assign positions to byhour, byminute, etc... I figured the only way was with multiple schedules (as in, my answer).  I'll have to keep that in mind.

Comment: @KrisJohnston It doesn't work on some older versions of Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to do this via: `FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=8,12;BYMINUTE=0,30;BYSECOND=0`, your job will run daily, 4 times per day (8AM, 8:30AM, 12PM, and 12:30PM), which doesn't sound like what you want.

I think the only way to do this is to create two schedules:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_schedule (
    schedule_name => 'EIGHT_AM',
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=8;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0');

  dbms_scheduler.create_schedule (
    schedule_name => 'TWELVE_THIRTY_PM',
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=12;BYMINUTE=30;BYSECOND=0');
end;
```

Then assign both schedules to the scheduler job:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.set_attribute('SCHEMA.MYJOB','REPEAT_INTERVAL','EIGHT_AM,TWELVE_THIRTY_PM');
```